# build.gradle buildscript dependencies vs. dependencies?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, classpath, build-script

Can someone explain to me how depedencies listed in the "buildscript" in the build.gradle file are different than regular dependencies listed in the dependencies block { } ? and why they have to be listed with the syntax "implementation"? I've googled this and responses say the dependencies in the buildscript and used to "build the project" but I don't understand this? can anyone give a more clear picture and answer?

**buildscript:**

```
buildscript
        {
            repositories
                    {
                        maven {
                            url 'myMavenFeed'
                            credentials {
                                username "myUsername"
                                password myPassword
                            }
                        }
                        mavenCentral()
                        jcenter()
                    }
            dependencies
                    {
                        classpath "com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.14.1"
                    }
        }
```

**Dependencies block:**

```
dependencies
        {
            compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot', name: 'iot-device-client', version: '1.16.0'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me how depedencies listed in the "buildscript" in the build.gradle file are different than regular dependencies listed in the dependencies block { } ?

Dependencies defined in the `buildscript { }` block are dependencies to use to build your project. These dependencies are available to use in your Gradle build file (`build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts`)

Dependencies defined in the `dependencies { }` are for your **application** code.

So for your samples in your questions, does it make sense for Gradle (the build system) to have `iot-device-client` on its classpath? Why does a build system need `iot-device-client` on its classpath to build your project? It doesn't make sense therefore it should be removed.

Now let's say you are developing an application the requires some functionality or class from `iot-device-client`. You need a way to add this library to your application's code/classpath. You when then declare it as a dependency as you have done above:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.16.0")
}
```

References:

- [External dependencies for the build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies)
- [Declaring depenedncies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)

> and why they have to be listed with the syntax "implementation"?

`implementation` is known as a [**configuration**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html): *A `Configuration` represents a group of artifacts and their dependencies*

There are many more configurations depending on the plugins you apply to your project. For example, if you apply the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html):

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}
```

The following configurations are available to use:

- implementation
- compileOnly
- compileClasspath
- ...and many more

Each one has their own meaning/usage and I strongly suggest reading about them [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations).